# Typescript function with function as parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I want to create a generic function that repeats tasks a certain number of times. It should receive another function and repeate it x times as the user wishes.

My generic function:

```js
export async function executeTask(task: (...args: any[]) => any, times: number) {
    // Validate the repeat parameter
    if (times <= 0 || !Number.isInteger(times))
        throw new Error('The repeat parameter should be a positive integer.');

    // Tasks promises results
    const tasksResults: Promise<any>[] = [];

    // Initialize the repeat counter
    let cycle = 0;
    while (cycle < times) {
        cycle++;
        // Add each task promise to the promises array
        tasksResults.push(task());
    }

    // Only return when all promises has resolved
    return Promise.all(tasksResults);
}
```

But the function I want to repeat has some optional parameters. See the func. signature:

```js
export async function executeSpeedTest(
    targetServerId?: number,
    outputFormat?: OutputFormat,
    outputUnit?: OutputUnit,
    showProgress?: boolean
) { }
```

The issue is that cannot call the repeater function and pass the function to be repeated with my optional params:

```js
const tasksResults = await executeTask(executeSpeedTest(18104), 3);
```

I receive the error:

> Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => any'. Type 'Promise' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any[]): any'.ts(2345)

It only works like this:

```js
const tasksResults = await executeTask(executeSpeedTest, 3);
```

I'm struggling on how I can use one wrapper function to repeat whatever other function and still being able to pass the inner function parameters.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

How about running the code like this?

```js
const tasksResults = await executeTask(() => executeSpeedTest(18104), 3);
```

This should work, since it's passing in a function that your `executeTask` function will call. The reason it doesn't work like this:

```
await executeTask(executeSpeedTest(18104))
```

is because you are *calling* `executeSpeedTest` when that line is executed, meaning it is taking the *result* of `executeSpeedTest`, which in this case appears to be a `Promise`.

Switching to the arrow function will ensure the code is only called when your calling function calls `task()`.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you could mark my answer as the correct answer, that'd help future readers find the question!

Comment: I still don't have enough reputation to cast a vote.